# Add file to a specific svn repository

Tags: svn, version-control

I have multiple svn code repositories.  How do I specify which repository I would like a file or folder to be added to ?

Something like
svn add file.php -r repository1

where i would set a flag in order to specify the repository name(repository1) in which i would like the file (file.php) added to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't add files to a repository, you add them to a [working copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.working-copy) of that repository (or part of it).  You then commit the changes to that working copy.  So put the file in the right place in the right working copy, then do `svn add`, and then do `svn commit`.

Comment: I have a file that i would like to be part of multiple repositories.  I dont want to just make a duplicate of the file and put it into another folder (because then if i make changes to 1 of the files, I would have to make them again in the other file).. where if i could add the same file to multiple repositories, then I would have one point of editing which would flow through to both repositories

Comment: Also, this is when I'm CREATING the repository for the first time (aka there are no working copies yet)

Comment: @user353877: You can use [externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html) for this.

Comment: @user353877: You can't put files into a repository that doesn't exist yet.  The general model is: create the repo, then check it out, then add files to the working copy, then commit.

Comment: the files do exist, but they are part of another repository (and they are in there own working directory)

Comment: with externals, would you go to the working svn directory for that repository, add an external that points to the file in another svn repository (that is remote??), and then the repository would check out that remote file when adding to the repository ?

Comment: in the short term, we used externals, but recently changed this to have a checkout bash script instead (where the bash script checks out all the repositories it needs).. oli answer helped point me in the right direction for properly understanding how to use svn